# Sheets API: How to append data to a sheets file ignoring the basic filters?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

When calling the `Method: spreadsheets.values.append` to a tab with Basic Filters enabled, the appended data will be placed at the end of the filtered values, instead of at the end of the file entire data. Is it possible to bypass this behaviour and always send data to the end of the file regardles of the filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, I cannot know your actual HTTP request of "Method: spreadsheets.values.append", in this case, how about the following flow?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, 1 process is used.
In this case, the batchUpdate method is used as follows.

```bash
curl --request POST \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"requests":[{"appendCells":{"rows":[{"values":[{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"sample"}}]}],"fields":"userEnteredValue","sheetId":0}}]}'
```

By this request, a value of "sample" is put to the next row of the last row of the sheet by ignoring the basic filter.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, 2 processes are used.

1. Retrieve all values from the sheet using "Method: spreadsheets.values.get" and retrieve the last row.

   - By checking the length of values, you can retrieve the last row.

   ```bash
   curl \
     'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/Sheet1' \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
     --header 'Accept: application/json'
   ```
2. Put the value to the next row of the last row using "Method: spreadsheets.values.update".

   - In this case, please set the next row of the last row of the sheet to the a1Notation of `Sheet1!A##`.

   ```bash
   curl --request PUT \
     'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/Sheet1!A##?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{"values":[["samplke"]]}'
   ```

By this flow, a value of "sample" is put into the next row of the last row of the sheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: It worked with batchUpdate. I haven't explored batchUpdate with appendCells before. I will be trying to use it through the Python client tomorrow. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Mauricio Thank you for replying. If that will be useful, I'm glad.